# Extract all elements from sets in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame where each cell is a set of numbers. I would like to go through the DataFrame and run each number along with the row index in a function. What's the most pandas-esque and efficient way to do this? Here's an example of one way to do it with for-loops, but I'm hopeful that there's a better approach.

```
def my_func(a, b):
    pass


d = {"a": [{1}, {4}], "b": [{1, 2, 3}, {2}]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

for index, item in df.iterrows():
    for j in item:
        for a in list(j):
            my_func(index, a)
```

Comment: kindly add your expected output dataframe

Comment: You mean `df.stack().explode().droplevel(1)`?

Comment: There are so many question on this topic, depending what your `my_func` looks like. The general answer is **NO**, loop it is, specially when you deal with object data. However, **in many cases**, one can re-write `my_func`  to utilized Pandas/Numpy vectorized functions. That said, `df.iterrows()` is slow...

Comment: @HenryEcker yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. Feel free to provide it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of iterating we can reshape the values into 1 column using [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) then [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) into separate rows:

`s`:

```
df.stack().explode()
```

```
0  a    1
   b    1
   b    2
   b    3
1  a    4
   b    2
dtype: object
```

We can further [`droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html) if we don't want the old column labels:

```
s = df.stack().explode().droplevel(1)
```

`s`:

```
0    1
0    1
0    2
0    3
1    4
1    2
dtype: object
```

[`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) can be used to create a DataFrame instead of a Series:

```
new_df = df.stack().explode().droplevel(1).reset_index()
new_df.columns = ['a', 'b']  # Rename columns to whatever
```

`new_df`:

```
   a  b
0  0  1
1  0  1
2  0  2
3  0  3
4  1  4
5  1  2
```

Answer (score 0):

If i fully understood your problem. This might be one way of doing it:

```
[list(item) for sublist in df.values.tolist() for item in sublist]
```

The output will look like this:

```
[[1], [1, 2, 3], [4], [2]]
```

Since this is a nested list, you can flatten it if your requirement is a single list.